# In Java, how to use one Semaphore for several processes?

Tags: java, multithreading, concurrency, scheduled-tasks, semaphore

I'm learning about Semaphores and how and when to use them, and from my understanding they are basically a signaller that lets processes know when there are none, one, or multiple resources available for use with the two simple functions `p(Semaphore)` and `v(Semaphore)` defined as:

```
public int p(Semaphore someSemaphore){
    if (someSemaphore == 0)
        // Put process into Queue
    else
        someSemaphore = someSemaphore - 1;
    return someSemaphore;

public int v(Semaphore someSemaphore){
    if (// Queue is not empty)
        // Take some process out of Queue and resume execution
    else
        someSemaphore = someSemaphore + 1;
    return someSemaphore;
```

I have a precedence graph with 9 processes T1 - T9

```
    T1
   /  \
  T2  T3
 /  \/  \
T4  T5  T6
 \  /\  /
  T7  T8
   \  /
    T9
```

where each process on the layer above points to the adjascent processes on the layer below (`T1` points to `T2` and `T3`; `T2` points to `T4` and `T5`; `T3` points to `T5` and `T6`; `T4` points to `T7`; `T5` points to `T7` and `T8`; `T6` points to `T8`; both `T7` and `T8` point to `T9`)

Using Semaphores I am required to to write psuedo code so that **maximum concurrency** can occur. An example for a basic presedence graph `T1 --> T2`:

```
Semaphore s = 0;

    synchronized void p1() = {
        T1;
        v(s);
    }

    synchronized void p2() = {
        p(s);
        T2;
    }
```

Here is what I have for the presedence graph of T1 - T9 shown above:

```
Semaphore s1 = 0;
Semaphore s2 = 0;
Semaphore s3 = 0;
Semaphore s4 = 0;

    synchronized void p1() = {
        T1;
        v(s1); // s1++;
    }

    synchronized void p2() = {
        p(s1); // s1--;
        T2;
        T3;
        v(s2); // s2++;
    }

    synchronized void p3() = {
        p(s2); // s2--;
        T4;
        T5;
        T6;
        v(s3); // s3++;
    }

    synchronized void p4() = {
        p(s3); // s3--;
        T7;
        T8;
        v(s4); // s4++;
    }

    synchronized void p5() = {
        p(s4); // s4--;
        T9;
    }
```

So, my question is: I know there is a way to do this with fewer than 4 Semaphores, so how is this accomplished? If I used fewer than 4 I run into the issue that any process (p2, p3, p4, p5) could start up once the Semaphore signals a resource is available because they are run concurrently. Any ideas?

Comment: You are using semaphores in binary mode..If you want to use lesser semaphores, then you can use use them in coutdownLatch mode...usually  a problem like this can be solved in countdownlatch mode

Comment: I don't know what a countdownlatch mode is. Could you please elaborate or provide some example code that follows this psuedo structure?